# Displaying unspecified number of text elements on single screen

Tags: ios, swift

There is a View Controller that receives a parameter from another View Controller and based on this parameter a function will parse a database and output a dictionary.

Output dictionary will look something like this:

`[String : [String, String, String], String : [String, String] ... ]`

Key will always have a single string, while value's number or strings is unknown.
Basically it will be a text screen with Titles (key) and following text (values).

My question is, what is the most appropriate way to display this text considering titles and text should have a different styling.

Comment: Best solution is to use `UITableView` with multiple section.

Comment: @NiravD thanks, I guess this is the answer. If you replay to my post, I will mark it as answered.

Comment: Welcome mate :), No need of it, you can post your own answer and please accept it, its great that you have made it :)